# Sort multi model elasticsearch by model weight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I am using this query to search across multiple models:

```
@search = Tire.search([User.index.name,Group.index.name,Product.index.name],load:false,from: from,per_page: results_per_page,size: results_per_page ) do
  query { string "#{q}*" ,:default_operator => 'AND'}
end
```

I want to sort the result based on model weight i.e the results from Product model should be first in the list. Is there any method in tire to do that ?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. Could you provide examples?

Comment: I want that results should be sorted according to the models. I want it in a sequence like... groups, products, users.

Comment: I think you need to use a custom_score for that. or a script that adds to the score depending on the type of the document.